# TypeError: req.on is not a function when using http-proxy with Nextjs 13 app router route handler

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js, http-proxy, next.js13

i'm trying to implement a proxy between Nextjs 13 App router and an external api using a route handler

```js
import { authOptions } from "@/modules/auth/utils/auth";
import httpProxy from "http-proxy";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
const ProxyHandler = async (req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse) => {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const proxy: httpProxy = httpProxy.createProxy();

    proxy.once("proxyRes", resolve).once("error", reject).web(req, res, {
      changeOrigin: true,
      target: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL,
    });
  });
};
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
    externalResolver: true,
  },
};
export {
  ProxyHandler as GET,
  ProxyHandler as POST,
  ProxyHandler as PUT,
  ProxyHandler as DELETE,
  ProxyHandler as PATCH,
};
```

`httpProxy` expects the client request to be `IncomingMessage` not `NextRequest`
i tried using `NextApiRequest`, didn't work
and rewrites aren't a solution for me since the purpose of the proxy is to append the accessToken on the server before making the call to external API
any solutions for this?

Comment: the only quick solution i could find for this is using the pages directory and creating an api route for the proxy